# What certification is needed for electronic devices in Europe?

Tags: emc, legal

I am going to be selling my project, Super OSD. It has a 3 MHz SMPS PSU and an 8 MHz crystal oscillator, but is not intended to emit radio signals. Will it be necessary to get testing to sell in Europe? I am selling from Europe, the UK to be specific.

Comment: What is Super OSD?  Is it a finished product for end consumers, or just a component for people to integrate in to their own things?

Comment: It's a hobbyist thing. For model planes. Not intended for the average user, it requires additional components to work properly, such as a GPS and video transmitter.

Comment: see here: http://code.google.com/p/super-osd

Comment: [Here is a question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5196/which-products-should-have-fcc-certification-and-about-how-much-does-that-cost) that discusses the FCC instead(USA).

Comment: @ThomasO, this now relates specifically to Europe as we have a question for FCC. This should allow more focused high quality answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To sell in the EU, you will need a CE mark, wheelie bin logo (WEEE) and RoHS statement.  You do not need to use an EU test house, but do need to be able to provide evidence to the authorities upon request for all of these.

If you are manufacturing in China, they will generally provide you with a RoHS statement.  If buying from China they will also provide the CE Mark (remember to ask for documentation).

Not sure about what is required to get an FCC mark.

Comment: by 'provide the CE mark' do you mean 'print the letters C and E in a round font' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking#China_Export , or actually perform the checks required to conformity?

Comment: you have linked to china export which is not the same as european CE marking.  For CE marking you do not need to perform any test.  However you need to demonstrate compliance against the standards.  The most straight forward method of demonstrating compliance is to have the conformity tests performed by a suitable test house!