# 'Contains FCC ID' compare to just 'FCC'. Certificate of conformity

Tags: fcc

I wanted to get FCC certification for my device.
The device uses WIFI module (FCC approved).

The testing house said the test will leverage on the WIFI module FCC test. 
Instead of getting FCC certification, I will get Certificate of Conformity.

I need to put "Contains FCC ID" xxx-xxxxx" on the product, instead of just "FCC" logo.

Is there any difference between putting "FCC" and "Contains FCC ID"?

Thanks!

Comment: FCC certification has been discussed before here. I would like to note what we have noted before, there is no way that our website can replace good legal advice or advice from an expert in FCC certification standards. If you are going to be selling a product and want to make sure that your product will meet FCC requirements you need to either have legal evidence from someone whom is licensed so that it is their insurance footing the bill if something goes wrong. Most users here could not foot the bill even if they wanted to.

Comment: Thanks @Kortuk! I assume you are from US. I realized in US everything must go through legal. My intention is to get an answer and I understand my responsibility & risk. In Asia, people don't sue(blame) each other for giving wrong advice. Especially when there is no written legal contract and payment involved. In any case, I still have to go through testing house.

Comment: if you incorrectly are doing your FCC work you can be liable for fines. In the US there are lawsuits, but they are not as bad in my opinion as news might make you think. If you are giving me interference due to poor design and incorrectly did your FCC cert you should get the hammer. On that note, FCC implies you are working in the US I believe

Comment: Again, thanks @Kortuk. Note taken! Certainly the test will be carried out by reputable testing house. The reason I asked initially was because I never see or heard about "Contains FCC ID" label. I thought the testing house offered me a "cheaper" / sub standard test :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your device has been fully tested to comply with FCC then you will be given an FCC ID.  This is the ID for your device.

It sounds like your device is only going to be partially tested, and that the majority of the testing will be taken as read by using the previous test of the WiFi module.  The WiFi portion of the device will not be tested.

I would guess that you are being told to put the ID of the WiFi module on the product for public inspection.  This will be so that the test for the WiFi can be obtained and read if required, as well as the test for your device.

Comment: Thanks Majenko. This is another answer that I have: FCC has many certification schemes.
1. Modular approval shows “Contains FCC ID: TEST123”
2. certification on end product shows “FCC ID: TEST123”
3. If product without wireless function but within FCC control scope, shows ”FCC”