# Why does my SSD have an FCC logo on it?

Tags: fcc

I just got my first SSD and on the back of it there are the common RoHS and No Trash logos but there is also an FCC logo.

Why would the FCC logo be on my SSD if it doesn't have any wireless radios in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by [this](http://www.supertalent.com/datasheets/SSD_Whitepaper_Compilation.pdf), in the "FCC Test Procedure" chapter, most likely to ensure that the SSD does not emit any kind of electromagnetic radiation that could harm or be detrimental to the computer's operation.

> Super Talent’s SSDs were tested by an independent testing laboratory for
>   Federal Communications Commission (FCC) certification. This is an official
>   recognition by the American government for products that meet inbound and
>   outbound radiation limits so it will not affect the communication of surrounding
>   products.

This question [Which products should have FCC certification and about how much does that cost?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/5196/8159) matters:

> In the US, all products containing electronics that oscillate above 9 kHz must be certified.

which most certainly is the case for SSDs, judging from [this](http://www.sitime.com/applications/storage-computing/ssd-solid-state-drive#magictabs_solutions_2) manufacturer of oscillators for SSD applications.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems sort of pointless though.  I mean, that's like getting a ballpoint pen FCC certified.  Of course it's not interfering with anything else!

Comment: The point is that computer hardware (specially SSDs, made of memory ICs operating at high speeds) often operates at very high frequencies internally, which could conceivably cause interference with other hardware.

Comment: I wonder if there's any nice way of designing a reasonably-precise microcontroller clock below 9kHz?  I've never seen crystals that low, though perhaps someone could make one.  I'm also curious whether it would be possible to incorporate an FCC-certified module that contained a 32KHz oscillator and a divide-by-four counter into a processor-controlled device without the latter having to be FCC certified?

Comment: If the 32KHz device is FCC certified and the processor doesn't produce any digital signals having a frequency of 9KHz or above (ie, on DIO lines, timers, etc) then you wouldn't need the divide by 4 would you?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cclab.com/fcc-part-15.htm

Unintentional radiators that have any type of rf emission potential are covered in part B.  Just missed other entry, but they are in agreement.